# why do I get int?

Tags: python, macos

I work on Mac, why do I always get integer, not fraction?

```
def dis(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    k = ( (x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2 )**1/2
    print(k)

x1 = int(input())

y1 = int(input())

x2 = int(input())

y2 = int(input())

dis(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

Comment: Probably your Mac has Python 2 installed, where `/` uses integer division if both parts are `int`. Use `... / 2.0` or `from __future__ import division` or upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: A minimal example would be "why does `3**1/2` evaluate to 1 in python2.7? I expect it to evaluate to the square root of 3."

Comment: Also, `**` binds stronger than `/`, so it should be `...**(1/2)` or `...**0.5`

Comment: please remark the python indentation(spacing) when you post a question

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a error. It should be:

```
def dis(x1,y1,x2,y2):
      k = ( (x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2 )**(1/2)
      print(k)
```

You have to write 1/2 between parenthesis, or you are doing ((...)**1)/2

Comment: if (1/2) is evaluated as 0, the function should always return 1 ((whatever)**0 = 1)!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python2, `/` is integer division if both parts are `int`s.

You want either

```py
def dis(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    k = ( (x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2 )**0.5  # you can also do (1/2.0)
    print(k)
```

or

```py
def dis(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    k = ( (x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2 )**1/2.0
    print(k)
```

(the last one doesn't make much sense)

Comment: Better yet, upgrade to Python 3 (I actually prefer the old semantics but Python 2 is obsolete).